# VBA that can delete a row from a range where there is no text, although the cell has a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I’m creating an automated report template that fits onto one page. This report includes bullet points and a chart. Because of a presentation request I need to make sure the chart always sits the same distance under the last bullet point. Unfortunately, there can be 7 bullet points or 2.  So automating this has become troublesome.

See image below, but my thinking is:

1. Specify a range (B11:B17)
2. Go to the bottom of that range and work up
3. Find empty cells in that range and delete entire row (issue 1)
4. Update the range variable to accommodate the change (unable to do)
5. Carry out the previous steps
6. Retrieve original range size and re-insert those rows where it should be
7. Go back to my original procedure to populate the bullets and then start at Step 1 again

VBA is something I struggle with, but find myself using more and more. I have searched and tried different ways to create a range and delete empty cells/rows. Some of them were dangerously bad. I’m starting with this simple code below now, but it’s not working:

```
Set MyFullRange = Range("B11:B17")
MyFullRange.Select
For CellRange = 1 To MyFullRange.Rows.Count
    If MyFullRange(CellRange).End(xlUp).Row = "" Then
        MyFullRange(CellRange).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next CellRange
```

[image]

**My issues**

1. The bullet rows are populated by referring to another sheet (=ProjectBullet_1, =ProjectBullet_2, etc.). Therefore  I’m having trouble recognising the empty cell and deleting the row accordingly.
2. Reinserting the rows so that it’s back to my original template structure. (*see possible alternative idea below*)
3. The bulleted rows appear in a certain part of the template $B$20:$B:$26. (below and above other populated rows) and previous attempts to delete rows have resulted in other empty rows being deleted.

Would it be easier (especially for step 6) if I simply copied the template sheet, called it something else and carried Steps 1 to 5 on the copy, deleting the copy once I exported it?

I know I need to break this issue down into pieces, but I'm struggling with the first piece.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide the rows instead of deleting them.

I've modified your code to hide the rows:

```
Public Sub hiderows()
    Dim thisrange As Range
    Set thisrange = ActiveSheet.Range("B11:B17")
    For CellRange = thisrange.Rows.Count + 10 To 11 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(CellRange, 2).Value = "" Then
            Rows(CellRange).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The keypoint is the line `If ActiveSheet.Cells(CellRange, 2).Value = "" Then` where I check the **value** of the cell. It reads the value, not the *formula*.

Comment: I hadn't even thought about hiding them! That would help me avoid a few difficult steps. Thanks.

Comment: The part of the code `+ 10 To 11 Step -1`. What's the reason for this? Understand the -1 principle but why `10 to 11`?

Comment: `thisrange.Rows.Count` gives the number of rows (7 for example), I'm adding 10 to start at  row 17. I know it can be done better but I was doing it as a quick test.

Comment: `vbnullstring` is pretty great..

Comment: Worked perfectly. Your hidden idea was a real "Doah" moment for me :) Thanks.